# C# Entity Framework 6 - code first - Data model for dynamic html table

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, entity-framework, reactjs

In one application we need to be able to create a table dynamically, meaning we do not know how many columns or rows the table will have and then save this to a database.

We can use this table from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro) as an example:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In this case our application needs to support that we add `Telephone` to the table for example.

My initial idea to support this was this data structure. It is ok to assume that a new header needs to have the same number of rows that already exist in the table for rows to appear on the correct position. Is this a good data structure or have I missed something? The values will be requested through an Http Api and then presented in a react front end.

```
public class Table
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TableData> TableData { get; set; }
}

public class TableData
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Header { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<string> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How many rows are you anticipating having in the database?

Comment: Why not just store as xml or json data?

Comment: Here table design is driven by number of columns and not number of rows. So your model should have columns collection and not rows. Single row is instance of collection columns.

Comment: @mjwills Not that many, lets say maximum 400-500 per table.

Comment: With this how would you add `Telephone`, would you just set the Header to Telephone? if the Rows..Column isn't there in Rows is it just blank. This could get tricky if you then later add another column as it then would represent to blanks and have a knock on effect, you will need to ensure that row delimiter matches number of distinct headers.

Comment: I also don't see how this would support multiple tables. Maybe that just because I'm expecting to see a foreign key between the two tables.

Comment: It looks like you are really tightly coupling your data model to your UI. Your database probably shouldn't need to know about HTML tables.
This is going to make your application very brittle if your UI requirements change, or you want to use the same data to do something different. I'd strongly suggest you build a data model with semantic meaning (Companies, Contracts, Countries etc.), expose it through the rest API and then use your front end to handle mapping that to a UI. After all, that's what a view library like react is for!